# Summation of a function 2

Tags: number-theory, summation, zeta-functions, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function

Let $n$ is a positive integer.

$n = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ is the complete prime factorization of $n$.

Let me define a function $f(n)$

$f(n) = p_1^{c_1}p_2^{c_2}\cdots p_k^{c_k}$ where $c_k = e_k - 1$

Example:

$72 = 2^33^2$, so $f(72) = 2^{3-1}3^{2-1} = 2^{2}3^{1}=12$

$144 = 2^43^2$, so $f(144) = 2^{4-1}3^{2-1} = 2^{3}3^{1}=24$

Now let $$F(N) = \sum_{n=2}^N f(n)$$

Example: $F(10) = 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 3 + 1 = 15$

Now I want to evaluate $F(N)$ for a fairly large value of $N$, say $10^{12}$. Can I do it without factorizing each number?

Comment: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18895?#comment-238962